# how to use makeMPICluster

Tags: r, mpi

Sorry for asking trivial question. I am using RMPI and snow for cluster. There isn't any return when makeMPICluster is called. But it works if mpi.spawn.Rslaves()  is callded

```
# method 1
library(snow)

library(Rmpi)

nclus=3

# no response
cl <-makeMPIcluster(nclus)

# method 2
library(Rmpi)
mpi.spawn.Rslaves()

4 slaves are spawned successfully. 0 failed.
master (rank 0, comm 1) of size 5 is running on:  
slave1 (rank 1, comm 1) of size 5 is running on:  
slave2 (rank 2, comm 1) of size 5 is running on: 
slave3 (rank 3, comm 1) of size 5 is running on: 
slave4 (rank 4, comm 1) of size 5 is running on:
```

Comment: are you sure there should be a return print statement.  have you tried executing code across the cluster?  maybe then we could get an error statment

Comment: @TomSwifty it just keeps waiting for the execution of 'cl <-makeMPIcluster(nclus)'. There should be '>' after one command is finished. In my case no '>'.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. I am using MPICH2  and windows 7 64bit, Rmpi 0.6.3(mpich2 version). And I tried with this code, also failed:  `mpi.spawn.Rslaves(); cl = getMPIcluster()`